# Debian Squeeze Kernel

Tags: debian, kernel, debian-squeeze

I'm running Debian Squeeze completely up to date on a machine. However when running `uname` I see that I'm on a very old kernel:

```
$ uname -r
2.6.32-5-amd64
```

Is this normal for Debian Squeeze? 
Should I upgrade? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. 2.6.32-5 is the current version of the kernel in Debian Squeeze. You'll notice the [linux-image-amd64](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/linux-image-amd64) dummy package lists linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64 as a dependency.

If you need a more recent version of the kernel you can get it from [backports](http://backports.debian.org/) where it is at version [3.2.0-0.bpo.4-amd64](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/linux-image-2.6-amd64).

Comment: I'll add: If you don't need a more recent version of the kernel for driver purposes, then you probably don't need to upgrade.  Debian backports patches for security problems (like the [recent ptrace race](http://www.debian.org/security/2013/dsa-2632) ) to their supported kernel version.

Answer (score -1):

**Squeeze** is a old stable version. The new stable version, **wheezy**, is in "*release candidate 1*" state, so an old kernel is normal in squeeze.

I suggest **upgrade to wheezy** or **activate "backports"**. Backports are new stuff ported to squeeze.

Comment: Squeeze is still the current-stable. Wheezy is still being tested and is expected to be released as stable relatively soon. There's still quite a few changes being made.